AWS RDS: I can't see my MariaDB db but I can see my MySQL db
I have an AWS RDS with MySQL engine and going migrate to MariaDB.
I created my MariaDB db from AWS Console but I can't see it in MariaDB client.
The settings of my MariaDB db is based from my MySQL db (same VPC, Subnet group, Subnets, VPC security groups and Security group rules. Only it have differents Availability Zone, Option groups and Parameter groups).
The connection to MariaDB db works but I not see my database.

The connection to MySQL db works and I see my database.

Please, any suggestion?
My databases:


What database are you expecting to see? How do you know that it exists?

I expect see my MariaDB db. I created it from AWS console.
Update: I added screenshot with both databases.

The 3rd screenshot is showing the database server or database instance, which is presumably what you are connecting to in your first screenshot. The 'logical' database within that server is most likely to be innodb or mysql unless you specified something different when launching the database server. It's quite confusing when a 'database server' has a similar name to a 'logical' database running on that server. In your picture of the MySQL connection, you'll notice that the 'logical' database is called My MySQL db, so you just need to figure out which one you are using in MariaDB.

I launched the MariaDB instance with a specific identifier ("myMaria", for example). Now I think "innodb" is my MariaDB instance, but I don't understand why it has that name and not the one I gave it ("myMaria").

If you click on the Database in the RDS console, a configuration screen should show the 'logical' database name that it is using.

In this section must enter the name of the database, otherwise none will be created.
Thanks @JohnRotenstein


